Rust scopes and borrowing in CSV tutorial
In the Rust csv module tutorial, under the Reading Headers section (about a third of the way down the page), there is a code example as follows:
//tutorial-read-headers-02.rs
fn run() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    {
        // We nest this call in its own scope because of lifetimes.
        let headers = rdr.headers()?;
        println!("{:?}", headers);
    }
    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result?;
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
    // We can ask for the headers at any time. There's no need to nest this
    // call in its own scope because we never try to borrow the reader again.
    let headers = rdr.headers()?;
    println!("{:?}", headers);
    Ok(())
}

Directly after that, there is this commentary:

One interesting thing to note in this example is that we put the call to rdr.headers() in its own scope. We do this because rdr.headers() returns a borrow of the reader’s internal header state. The nested scope in this code allows the borrow to end before we try to iterate over the records. If we didn’t nest the call to rdr.headers() in its own scope, then the code wouldn’t compile because we cannot borrow the reader’s headers at the same time that we try to borrow the reader to iterate over its records.

I'm just learning Rust and I figured it would be useful to see what the compiler error looks like if the extra scope was removed.
//tutorial-read-headers-02.rs
fn run() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    
    let headers = rdr.headers()?;
    println!("{:?}", headers);
    
    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result?;
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
    // We can ask for the headers at any time. There's no need to nest this
    // call in its own scope because we never try to borrow the reader again.
    let headers = rdr.headers()?;
    println!("{:?}", headers);
    Ok(())
}

The above code compiles with no issues using rustc 1.77.2 (25ef9e3d8 2024-04-09).
Is this something that has changed since the tutorial was written or was this always unecessary? If it has changed, where can I find information about the change i.e.: why was it needed originally but not now?

Documentation is wrong/outdated it seems. Try going back a couple more Rust versions.

@8192K That's what I figured but I am more interested in what changed and why.

headers is a simple reference so this code would've had to been written before non-lexical lifetimes. The borrow checker sees that headers isn't used after the println! so it knows it can't conflict with the .records() call.

@kmdreko Thanks. If you write that up as an answer, I will accept it.
